# Equating coefficients of polynomials in Z5

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory

I am trying to get my head around this example given in my lecture notes. I understand the method behind it but I'm struggling with the step where $q$ and $r$ are found. I have attempted to equate coefficients by multiplying out the bracket and have got a completely different answer to the one given. I suspect it may be something to do with the fact that it is in the integers modulo 5 but I'm not sure. Please see the question attached, thankyou.

Let $f = x^5 + 3x^4 + 2x^2 + 4, g = 2x^2 + 1 $ $ \epsilon$ $ \mathbb{Z}_{5}[x].$

Find $q, r $ $ \epsilon$ $ \mathbb{Z}_{5}[x]$ with
$r(x) = 0 $ or $deg (r) < deg (g) $ such that $f = gq + r$

Answer: We know that $r = 0$ or $deg (r) = 0$ or $1$; also, $deg (q) = 3$.

So we can either write:

$q = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d, r = ux + v $

so that:

$f = x^5 + 3x^4 + 2x^2 + 4 = (2x^2 + 1)(ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d)+(ux + v)$,

and equate coefficients,
or use long division for polynomials.

We find:

$q = 3x^3 + 4x^2 + x + 4, r = 4x$

Comment: Can you show your work? I did the problem with polynomial long division and agree with the solution.

Comment: $(2x^2 +1)(ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d) + (ux + v)$


= $2ax^5 + 2bx^4 + (2c + a)x^3 + (2d + b)x^2 + (c + v)x + d + v$


so $2a = 1 , 2b=3 , a+2c = 0, b+2d = 2 , u+c = 0 & d+v=4$

Then solving for the unknowns and I get a very different answer to the one given. I've repeated it but got the same answer @law-of-fives

Comment: $2\cdot a = 1$ has just a single solution mod 5, which is $3$. So $a=3$. Similarly with $b$ Then you can use this to find c and d. Etc. Where did you go wrong, exactly?

Comment: @law-of-fives stupidly treated it like it was in R not Z5, rookie mistake